# How to clear tasks out of a Celery queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to purge a list of tasks in a rabbitmq / celery queue.

I used the following:

```
root@ip-10-150-115-164:/my-api# celery amqp queue.purge celery
-> connecting to amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//.
-> connected.
ok. 0 messages deleted.
```

Why are 0 messages being deleted when there are over 12,000 in the queue?

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues
celeryev.fdc87318-5013-465c-92be-e3081ed3c579   0
worker5@ip-10-150-115-164.celery.pidbox 0
celeryev.218186c8-49d3-4601-8237-3edcb17ca82a   0
celery  12485
worker1@ip-10-150-115-164.celery.pidbox 0
worker3@ip-10-150-115-164.celery.pidbox 0
worker4@ip-10-150-115-164.celery.pidbox 0
worker2@ip-10-150-115-164.celery.pidbox 0
celeryev.616cf756-77fb-48fc-aa3c-a9a53e909ba1   0
celeryev.29bf149e-592c-4f82-990a-1a72c2830bb2   0
celeryev.c35d971e-80b1-492f-a111-6be576f6c825   0
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `celery -A your.project.app purge -Q celery` ?

Comment: I did, it kept saying 0 messages deleted. I restarted rabbitmq, it deleted 9000, restart again and did more etc. Can't be right but queue cleared.

Comment: Did you try purging the queue from the rabbitmq management UI or CLI?